# Send the output from a startup script to any new notebook in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have a [startup file](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files) that looks like this

```py
if os.getenv("ENV") == "prod" or os.getenv("MASTER_DB_HOST") == "db.domain.com":
    from colorama import Fore, Style
    print(f"{Fore.RED}WARNING!!!") 
    print(f"{Style.DIM}It seems you are running in a PROD like environment (or against the PROD database)")
from my_app.models import Foo, Bar
```

So when I run IPython this warning message is shown if needed

[image: ipython show startup output]

When I use `jupyter lab` this script is also executed (because the imported objects are available ) but I would like to get the output in the first cell of any notebook. Is this possible?

Alternatively, could I define a default notebook to start with and run it automatically?